# PHP 4 and 5, Ctrl-C, system(), and child processes

Tags: php, windows, system, children, copy-paste

I have a PHP script that uses the `system()` call to execute other (potentially long-running) programs (for interest: NCBI BLAST, phrap, primer3 and other programs for doing DNA sequence analysis and assembly).

I'm running under Windows XP, using the CLI version of PHP from a command prompt, or as a service. (In either case I communicate with it via a queue of tasks in a database table).

Under PHP4: when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the script is stopped and any child process running at the time is also stopped.
Under PHP5: when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the script stops, but the child is left running.

Similarly, when running the script as a service, stopping the service when running it with PHP4 stops the child, with PHP5 the child continues to run.

I have tried writing a minimal test application, and found the same behaviour. The test PHP script just uses system() to execute a C program (that just sleeps for 30 seconds) and then waits for a key to be pressed.

I had a look at the source for PHP 4.4.9 and 5.2.6 but could see no differences in the system() code that looked like they would cause this. I also had a quick look at the startup code for the CLI application and didn't see any differences in signal handling.

Any hints on what might have caused this, or a workaround, would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is the desired behavior?

Comment: The PHP 4 behaviour - with the children stopping too.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs in at least PHP 5.1.2.

When a SIGINT is sent via CTRL+C or CTRL+BREAK, the handler is called. If this handler sends a SIGTERM to other children, the signals are not received.

SIGINT can be sent via posix_kill() and it work exactly as expected-- This only applies when initiated via a hard break.

From: http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php

The document has sample code for trapping CTRL+C and sending posix_kill to children.
It has lots of other code and info on child precesses and signals.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using system(), have a look at [proc_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php), [proc_close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) and [proc_terminate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php).